# How, in eclipse do I work with an existing maven project in GitHub without ending up checking my .project file?

Tags: git, github, maven, eclipse

I have a maven project in GitHub that I wish to work with using eclipse.

I want to keep the GitHub repository clear of any eclipse project artifacts such as the .project file.

Is there a way to do the following (or alternative that accomplishes the same):

1. Have two GitHub projects -- one being the pure maven project
2. The other being the eclipse project
3. Using eclipse project organization features to keep them separate

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: @esoterik -- are you objecting to the wording? the question in general? do you know enough about the eclipse, GitHub, and Maven to evaluate the question as not meeting the criteria?

Comment: https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7091/making-best-practices-questions-more-palatable-how-to-ask-a-best-practice-q https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142353/why-is-asking-a-question-on-best-practice-a-bad-thing I think i have been conditioned to see "Is there a best practice ..." as poor quality; looking at your question, now, it is on the line for build/workflow questions.

Comment: Thanks I changed some words to make it more specific -- so there is possibly one answer

Comment: [Submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) maybe?

Comment: @submodules -- let me look into that thaks

Answer (score 0):

Git will look for a `.gitignore` file, which describes what files should be ignored by git.  Could you add entries in .gitignore for all of the files that you don't want ending up on GitHub?

Comment: I guess one could do that -- but then I wouldn't have my eclipse project under git. Is there a way to keep the two separate?

Comment: @user1172468 - the idea is actually to make the IDE (Eclipse) orthogonal to and independent from the **build system** (Maven).  That is, the use of a particular IDE (platform or version) should be irrelevant to whether your project successfully builds.  This makes it much easier to do things like set up CI/CD - they don't need the IDE, just a reference to the build system.  It also means migrating to different IDEs, or supporting multiple IDEs, is much easier

Comment: For practical considerations, the standard now seems to be to use something like the Maven wrapper with a pinned version (prevents build-tool changes affecting the project building successfully).  In terms of Eclipse, you **really** don't want the project files added to the repository, because they can include things that are local to your machine (although I think they've gotten better at that over the years).  What you would normally do is clone the repository, and then import as a Maven project, which _should_ cause the correct Eclipse project setup to happen.